# Why Qt is throwing error for lambda expression in signal and slot?

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I have a function (public slot)

```
void Parts::Testing(QString text)
{
    ui_add_new_part->lineEdit_InvoiceNumber->setText(text);
}
```

that is connected to signal of QCompleter as

```
connect(completer_part_invoice, SIGNAL(activated(QString)),
                    this, SLOT(Testing(QString)));
```

The purpose of the above code is, whenever i use complete() function from QCompleter, the suggestions pop up on line edit and upon clicking a suggestion, that particular text should come on the line edit.

The above code works as I expect

**Problem**
Since the function has only one statement I want to use lambda expression in the connect function itself. Thereby saving code length and Improving readibility.
Upon googling I found [this](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax). Upon referring the site I wrote code like this

**Try 1**

```
connect(
    completer_part_invoice, &QCompleter::activated,
    [&]( const QString &text )
    {
    ui_add_new_part->lineEdit_InvoiceNumber->setText(text);
});
```

But Qt is throwing the error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Parts::connect(QCompleter*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, Parts::pop_Up_Invoices()::<lambda(const QString&)>)'
             );
         ^
```

**Try 2**

```
connect(
    completer_part_invoice, SIGNAL(activated(QString)),
    [&]( const QString &text )
    {
    ui_add_new_part->lineEdit_InvoiceNumber->setText(text);
});
```

But Qt threw error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'Parts::connect(QCompleter*&, const char [20], Parts::pop_Up_Invoices()::<lambda(const QString&)>)'
             });
              ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Try3**

As pointed in comments I also tried

```
connect(
    completer_part_invoice, QOverload<const QString &>(&QCompleter::activated),
    [&](const QString &text)->void
    {
    ui_add_new_part->lineEdit_InvoiceNumber->setText(text);
});
```

Error I got

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'QOverload<const QString&>::QOverload(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
                 completer_part_invoice, QOverload<const QString &>(&QCompleter::activated), 

                                                                                    ^
```

Comment: You should add `this` as the receiver of your lambda-slot, because otherwise the signal could execute the lambda et try to access `ui_add_new_part` even if your object has been destroyed, it is a good practice.

Comment: @G.M. I tried all the possible solutions from their, but it did not help

Comment: @ymoreau I tried [this, &] as well as [&, this] also tried [this] but did mot help either

Comment: @king_nak the answers have the almost same solution as first pointed by G.M

Comment: @guru I didn't mean to pass `this` in the lambda, but to use as receiver of the slot, in the connect function `connect(pointer, &Class::signal, this, [&](...`

Comment: 1. It is `QOverload<T>::of(...)` or `qOverload<T>(...)`. 2. What Qt version do you use? 3. What compiler&version / C++ version do you use?

Comment: @king_nak thanks that worked.. I am using Qt 5.10.1. Compiler mingw 5.3.0. C++ Version I think its default of Qt i.e C++11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `QCompleter` has two overloads of `activated`. You need to specify which one you want to use:

```
connect(completer_part_invoice, QOverload<const QString&>::of(&QCompleter::activated),
    this, [&](const QString& text) {
        ui_add_new_part->lineEdit_InvoiceNumber->setText(text);
});
```

It's [in the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#activated), actually. Your **Try 3** is missing `::of` after `QOverload<const QString &>`.

Comment: oops, it's all in the comments already

Answer (score 2):

The way you use the new call syntax makes it ambiguous. Compare:

```
connect(obj, SIGNAL(activated(QString)), ...)
```

with

```
connect(obj, &Class::activated, ...)
```

The type information about `activated` is missing, the compiler has to deduct it. The problem is: there are two overloads of that method:

```
void C::activated(const QString &text)
void C::activated(const QModelIndex &index)
```

With more advanced template machinery, the `connect` could be made to select overloads based on the types in the receiver side of the connection. But it's not implemented yet. That's why Qt provides `QOverload` and `qOverload`, so that you don't have to write awkward casts yourself. Allversions below are equivalent; the `qOverload` one is a bit less verbose but requires a newer compiler. The `QOverload` works on all compilers that current Qt supports.

```
connect(obj, QOverload<QString>::of(&Class::activated), ...)
connect(obj, qOverload<QString>(&Class::activated), ...)
connect(obj, static_cast<void(Class::*)(const QString&)>(&Class::activated), ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `const` from this part **( const QString &text )**

Comment: That did not solve the issue

Comment: @guru also remove this sign '&' before 'text'

Comment: I had tried that too

Comment: That's just bad advice. `const QString &` is how you're supposed to pass any non-trivial value in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after lots of trial and error from the answers mentioned in comments, I was able to compile without errors and it worked

```
        connect(
            completer_part_invoice, static_cast<void (QCompleter::*)(const QString&)>(&QCompleter::activated),
            [&](const QString &text)->void
            {
            ui_add_new_part->lineEdit_InvoiceNumber->setText(text);
        });
```

Thank you everyone

**Edit**: As stated in comments and others answers, i was missing "of" in try 3
Now this also works

```
        connect(completer_part_invoice, 
                QOverload<const QString&>::of(&QCompleter::activated),
            this, [&](const QString& text) {
                ui_add_new_part->lineEdit_InvoiceNumber->setText(text);
        });
```